# GPS Based AR: Get x,y Coordinate for Lat and Long

Tags: three.js

I am trying to find the x and y coordinate for given longitude and latitude. I want to display cubes in three.js in my application using the x and y coordinates. I used the following formula:

```
public calcPosFromLatLonRad ( lat: number, lon: number, radius: number ) {
        var phi   = (90 -  lat) * (Math.PI / 180);
        var theta = (lon + 180) * (Math.PI / 180);
        const x = -(radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta));
        const z = (radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta));
        const y = (radius * Math.cos(phi));
        console.log('x Koordinate: ' + x + ' y Koordinate: ' + y + 'z Koordinate: ' + z);
        return [x, y, z];
    }
```

Then I tried:

```
const x1 = this.calcPosFromLatLonRad(52.387980, 9.719260, 100);
        const pos1x = x1[0];
        const pos1y = x1[1];
        const pos1z = x1[2];

cube2.position.set(pos1x, pos1y, pos1z);
camera.position.z = 5;
        scene.add( cube2);
const animate  = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
```

But I don’t see anything on my display. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your camera does not look at the cube. Try it with `camera.lookAt( pos1x, pos1y, pos1z )`.

Comment: I have multiple Elements on my Screen. I want to map 3 Elementes including their GPS-Coordinates. When I move my Smarphone with DeviceOrientationController, they should be on the right place. With your advice, my camera will only look at one Element.  How can I solve this?

Comment: In this case try to move the camera farther away. Instead of `5` try it with `200`.

Comment: I did, but this didn't solved my problem. My coordinate system is like "somewhere" when I open the camera and the objects I place are in this coordinate system. I want to try the instrutcions of AR.js. It says that I have to set my Original GPS Position as the world origin. How can I do that?